# Angular js query not running

Tags: angularjs

I had tried to run the `jqgrid` using `angularjs`, but i did not get any output.

I had uses the following:

**HTML**

```
 <html ng-app="myApp">  
    <head>  
        <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>  
        <link data-require="jqgrid@*" data-semver="4.5.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.5.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />  
        <script data-require="jqgrid@*" data-semver="4.5.2" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.5.2/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>  
        <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />  
        <style type="text/css"></style>  
        <script src="ngtest.js">  
        
        </script>  
    </head>  
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">  
        <ng-jq-grid config="config" data="data"></ng-jq-grid>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]);
         myApp.directive("ngJqGrid", function ($compile) {
        return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            config: "=",
            data: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var $grid;

            scope.$watch("config", function (newValue) {

                element.children().empty();
                $grid = angular.element("<table id='" + $.jgrid.jqID() + "'></table>");
                element.append($compile($grid)(scope));

                element.append($grid);
                angular.extend(newValue, {
                    autoencode: true,
                    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                    cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true }, 
                    autoResizing: { compact: true },
                    autoresizeOnLoad: true,
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        $compile(this)(scope);
                    }
                });

                angular.element($grid)
                    .jqGrid(newValue)
                    .jqGrid("navGrid")
                    .jqGrid("filterToolbar");
            });
            scope.$watch("data", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $grid.jqGrid("clearGridData");
                $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {data: newValue});
                $grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.config = {
        myClick: function (rowid) {
            alert("Test buton is clicked on rowid=" + rowid);
        },
        colNames: ["Client", "", "Date", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Notes"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "name", align: "center", width: 65, editrules: {required: true},
                searchoptions: { sopt: ["tcn", "tnc", "teq", "tne", "tbw", "tbn", "tew", "ten"] }},
            { name: "myLink", align: "center",
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return "<button class='btn btn-primary' popover-placement='top' popover='" +
                         rowObject.note + "' ng-click='config.myClick(" + options.rowId + ")'>Test</button>";
                }},
            { name: "invdate", width: 125, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" },
                editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
            { name: "closed", width: 70, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" },
            { name: "ship_via", width: 105, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
            { name: "amount", width: 75, template: "number" },
            { name: "tax", width: 52, template: "number", hidden: true },
            { name: "total", width: 60, template: "number" },
            { name: "note", width: 60, sortable: false, edittype: "textarea" }
        ]
    };
    $scope.data = [
        { id: "11",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: 0, tax: 0, closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: 0 },
        { id: "21",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: 351.75, tax: 23.45, closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: 375.2 },
        ....etc
    ];
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m23tutpc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of things going on:

- You need to load external resources on the left panel when using `jsfiddle`.
- When using `jsfiddle` you do not include a `header` it is automatically included in the output
- You didn't include the `angular-ui-bootstrap` javascript files that you have as a dependency
- You are using an older version of angular which does not pair with angular-ui-bootstrap, I updated the angular dependency to **1.3.20** to get things to run
- When using jsfiddle with angular you need to select `No wrap - in <body>` from the options on the left or it will not run angular.
- You are trying to bind the app to the `DOM` twice, you only need one `ng-app="myApp"`
- And you have functions you are calling such as `initDateEdit` and `initDateSearch` which where not defined

All that being said, making these changes the app will load in jsfiddle.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/q8gur65w/)

Comment: i got output in jsfiddle but i trying to do this with in editor and save it as .html file i didnt get output frnd  :(                                                                                                                              please help  me and the values that i had provided also not displayed in the jqgrid why??